# Etymology of "fairy"

Tags: etymology, linguistics, french, roots, research

All the standard dictionaries--with the notable exception of the OED--seem to trace the etymology of *fairy* through Old French *fae* to Latin *fata*, meaning "the fates" or "the goddess of fate". As a classical languages major with primary focus on Latin, I find this etymology of *fairy* doubtful. I can buy the origin from French, but the French connection to *fata* seems strained.

I'm familiar with the apotropaic "fair folk" being used in place of "fairy," but am inclined to think that this usage is based on an incorrect folk etymology that assumes *fairy* comes from *fair*, which in fact seems to be unrelated, coming from Teutonic sources.

The OED traces to Old French in the same way, but--interestingly to me--does not trace further.

Would anyone be willing to explain how *fata* would be transformed into *fae*? Thank you!

Comment: I gave you a +1 but I wish I could give you a +100. If we got questions like this every day, I'd be a happy man.

Comment: [Lenition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenition) of intervocalic unvoiced stops in Romance languages went the furthest in French. In Spanish they become voiced. In French they eventually get dropped altogether. Examples L pater -> Sp padre, Fr pere, L dicere -> Sp decir, Fr dire. The usual lenition chain here is p->b->v->ø, or t->d->th->ø, or k->g->γ->ø

Comment: Actually, the OED does trace to Latin *fata*; you just have to look at the cross-reference in the etymology to the entry for **fay** ("<  *fae* , *fee* fay n.2 + *-erie* -ery *suffix*."): "< Old French *fae*, *faie* (French *fée* ) = Provençal *fada* , Portuguese *fada* , Spanish *hada* , Italian *fata* < Common Romance *fāta* feminine singular, < Latin *fāta* the Fates, plural of *fātum* fate *n*."

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to Wiktionary, Galician, Catalan and Occitan have a word [*fada*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fada#Galician) "fairy" and Italian has *[fata](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fata#Italian)* with the same meaning, which seems like a clear confirmation of a Vulgar Latin form *fata meaning "fairy". (And as tchrist points out, Spanish has *[hada](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hada#Spanish),* because it had a historical change of /f/ to /h/ in many contexts.) I don't know if there are any alternative explanations for this aside from a derivation from Latin *fatum/fata*.

The phonological development from fata > French fée is quite straightforward: intervocalic t was lenited and lost in French, word-final a was turned to schwa, represented by the letter "e", and stressed "a" was in many circumstances fronted and raised in French, here to /e/ "é", similar to the development of the past participle suffix "-é(e)" from Latin *-ātus/-āta.* (There are alternative spellings, some of which may correspond to slightly different vowels.) There are many other examples of these sound changes; e.g. Fr. *chaîne* < Lat. *catena* also shows the loss of intervocalic "t" and change of final "a" to "e".

I'm not sure how to explain the semantic development but it doesn't seem too far-fetched to me.

As you can see in the OED entry, the *-ry* part of *fairy* comes from the *-ery* suffix; French *faerie/faierie/farie/[féerie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/f%C3%A9erie)* was an abstract noun referring to magic or the realm of the fairies, which seems to have developed in English into a collective noun and then finally the current singular meaning. The OED records earlier uses in English that were closer to the sense of the French word:

> 1. Enchantment, magic. Also: an instance of this; an illusion, a dream; a dazed or excited state of mind. *Obs.* [...]
> 2. a. A magical or enchanted land or domain; the (imaginary) realm or world of fairies (sense A. 3a); fairyland; = *faerie* n. 2. [...]
>
>    b. Chiefly with *the.* The supernatural or magical beings inhabiting such a realm; fairies (sense A. 3a) collectively. Cf. *faerie* n. 1b. Somewhat rare in later use.

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fata/

Comment: Thank you for your help! The etymology makes sense to me now.

Comment: Don't forget that Spanish has *hada* there with the standard f > h change.

Comment: It's nice when someone knows something!

Comment: You explained fai- but you did not explain -ry.

Comment: Note that all of these changes from the Latin took place entirely within French before it was borrowed into English.

Answer (score -1):

"fairy" is literally identical to "pari" of Persian with exactly the same meaning. "fata" is too contrived.

An Indo-Iranian origin seems most likely.