# Are the words “fact” and “fairy” etymologically related?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Bruno Latour remarks in a 2003 lecture that “fact and fairy are etymologically related but I won’t develop this point here”.

> We can summarize, I estimate, 90 percent of the contemporary critical
>   scene by the following series of diagrams that fixate the object at only two positions, what I have called the *fact* position and the *fairy* position—**fact and fairy are etymologically related but I won’t develop this point here**. The fairy position is very well known and is used over and over again by many social scientists who associate criticism with antifetishism. The role of the critic is then to show that what the naïve believers are doing with objects is simply a projection of their wishes onto a material entity that does nothing at all by itself… Is it not time for some progress? To the *fact* position, to the *fairy* position,
>   why not add a third position, a *fair* position?
>
> <sub>[Why Has Critique Run out of Steam?](http://corner-college.com/udb/cpro8U99avWhy_has_critique_run_out_of_steam.pdf) From Matters of Fact to Matters of Concern</sub>

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy#Etymology), the word *fairy* has several variants: *fay*, *fae*, *fair folk*; *faery*, *faerie* and is derived from the Latin *fata*. The suffix *-erie* (-(e)ry) was added to *faie* to become *faierie*, and signified the land where Faes dwelled. Whereas *fact* is derived from the Latin *factum*.

But what is the connection between *fact* and  *fairy* that Latour mentions?
Are there any leads on this?

Comment: Did you, in [fact](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fact&allowed_in_frame=0), check either or both etymologies in a dictionary? Or do you think of anonymous strangers on the internet as your personal research [fairies](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fairy&allowed_in_frame=0)? Kidding aside, I really don't understand why people jump on the internet to ask questions like this rather than just look up the answers directly for themselves! Maybe people don't know dictionaries (paper and electronic) contain etymologies? Can you enlighten me?

Comment: @DanBron what's a dictionary? I'd look it up but, you know.

Comment: @DanBron While this shows little research into the potential *answer*, it's a nice question of a *possibly* little known etymology. I think that it deserves an answer. Huppuguga, consider showing any research results that might point to whether this is easily proven true, and this question will be improved. Inherently, I think it'd be nice to have on this stack.

Comment: Here’s what you do, huppuguga: You add a paragraph to your question saying, “Etymology Online traces [_fact_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fact&allowed_in_frame=0) to Latin _factum_ (‘an event, occurrence, deed, achievement’) and before that to Indo-European *_dhe_  (‘to set, put’), and it traces [_fairy_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fairy&allowed_in_frame=0) to Latin _fata_ (‘the Fates’) and before that to Indo-European *_bha_ (‘to speak, tell, say’). So where’s the connection that Latour was talking about?” That takes care of your lack-of-research problem. ...

Comment: ... Then we can all turn our attention to arguing about whether a question that may hinge on the relation between seemingly different Indo-European roots is sufficiently about the English language to be on topic at this site.

Comment: @SvenYargs We don't have to argue about whether it's on topic at all; the answer is *no*. If OP had looked for himself first he wouldn't have needed to ask at all. The problem with easily-researched questions isn't topicality so much as a combination of [a lack of] courtesy and interest. We had one of the site's foremost experts answer this question, and what did we learn from it we couldn't have learned from reading the dictionary? Personally, only the bit he put in a comment under his own answer. The tl;dr version of the rest is "there's as much connection as between *banana* & *horseshoe*".

Comment: @DanBron: I was living in the narrow world of Review Queue entries and didn't even notice that there was an answer in place—much less that it was from John Lawler. Nevertheless, if I had heard Bruno Latour say that _fact_ and _fairy_ are etymologically related, and I thought that he wasn't just talking through his hat, and I checked Etymonline's treatment of the two words, I might very well have felt justified in wondering, "Is Latour sowing bullcorn or is there something about the connection that Etymonline is missing?" I guess it depends on whether you think Etymology Online is dispositive.

Comment: ... This does not mean that the poster shouldn't be expected to check there or in a dictionary before proceeding with the question, of course, which I take to be the core of your criticism. But I can imagine going forward with the question after having checked those resources—depending on how inclined I was to take offhand remarks from Bruno Latour seriously.

Comment: @SvenYargs Yes, you hit it on the nose. My core complaint is *do your own legwork* (where that legwork is obvious) **before** asking people to help you out. I would have warmly received this Q If OP had framed it the way you advise in your first comment. I don't expect people to use or even be aware of Etymonline, or have access to the expensive OED. Nor do I think those sources dispositive or error-free. But I *do* expect it to occur to them to check *some* dictionary first, or even do the token "<word> etymology" google search, & embed what they found in the first draft of their question.

Comment: @SvenYargs I've taken the initiative to add the "research" and include your suggested comment. If I've made a mess of this, please edit!

Comment: @Mari-LouA: You've done a nice job of it, and I think that the question is of potential interest to other people who encounter the passage in Latour's book, either first-hand or second-hand. I also think that John Lawler's answer is valuable and should settle the question for all. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly relevant: There is a chapter on Bruno Latour in Sokal and Bricmont's book _Impostures Intellectuelles_ (translated into English as *Fashionable Nonsense: Postmodern Intellectuals' Abuse of Science* and in the UK as *Intellectual Impostures: Postmodern philosophers’ abuse of science*). (Some related pages I found online just now: [1](http://www.math.tohoku.ac.jp/~kuroki/Sokal/bricmont/node16.html#SECTION00052000000000000000), [2](http://www.physics.nyu.edu/sokal/le_monde_english.html).)

Comment: Thanks, ad hominem commentariat for your assumptions. Your substantive answers, when they could be spotted among the barrage of judgements, were educating though. Not being a linguist or an academic, my resources on private broadband are limited. Did I do my etymology check before bothering everyone here? Well, I wasn't looking for an answer about what does the OED or M-W say about their origins. Wouldn't waste your valuable time here if that's what I were looking for.

My bad though that I didn't spell out what I was looking for in detail.

Answer (score 11):

No, they're not related. Both do come from Latin words, but not from the same Latin words.

***Fairy***, or *faerie*, is a French word derived from *fé*, a descendant of the Latin word *fidēs*, 'faith'.
Here's what the OED says about it:

> The L. *fidēs*, like its etymological cognate Gr. πίστις (pístis),
>    which it renders in the N.T., had the following principal senses:
>     1. Belief, trust.
>     2. That which produces belief, evidence, token, pledge, engagement.
>     3. Trust in its objective aspect, troth; observance of trust, fidelity.

*Fidēs* in turn comes from the PIE root [**bʰeydʰ*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/b%CA%B0eyd%CA%B0-) 'to trust'.

***Fact***, however, is from *factum*, a form of the Latin verb *facere*  'make, do, accomplish'.
Originally, *fact* in English meant 'a thing done or performed; action, deed, course of conduct'.
Nowadays we're more likely to use *fact* about states and abstractions, but originally it referred to events and actions only.

*Facere* comes from the PIE root [**dʰeh₁*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%CA%B0eh%E2%82%81-) 'to do, put, place'

Interestingly, the etymological roots do still distinguish the two senses. 
*Fairies* are imaginary,
and depend on human belief,  while *facts* are actual, and have no need for belief; they just are.

Comment: P.S. Note that Latin /f/ can come from either a PIE *_bʰ_ or a PIE *_dʰ_. That's because the PIE aspirated stops got lost and reinterpreted (often as /f/) in Latin, the same way the PIE labiovelar stops like *_gʷ_ got reinterpreted and smeared across the mouth as labials, dentals, or velars in Greek.

Comment: Isn't ["fairy" (or more specifically, "fée") rather from *fata*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/391779/77227)? And "fides" seems to have become *foi,* in accordance with the sound change in French of /e/ > /oi/ > /wɛ/ > /wa/

Answer (score 3):

*Fact* and *fairy* aren't etymologically related, but John Lawler's answer is probably not correct when it states that *fairy* is related to Latin *fidēs.* 
According to regular vowel changes, *fidēs* corresponds to the French word *foi* 'faith'. The Old French form *fei,* which is the source of an obsolete English word "fay" meaning "faith", looks a bit more similar to *fairy* in form, but as far as I know was not used with a "fairy"-related meaning.

The usual etymology given for French *fée* 'fairy' (in Old French also spelled *fae* or *faie*) is instead that it is related to Latin *fātum* 'fate, doom' via the plural form *fāta,* which you mention. This plural form is supposed to have been reinterpreted as a singular feminine noun, which was a common development for Latin neuter plural forms. Regular Latin-to-French sound changes get us from *fāta* to *faie/fae/fée.*

*Fātum/fāta* in turn is supposed to come from the Latin verb *[for](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for#Latin)* 'speak', which Wiktionary says is from a PIE root that is reconstructed as **bʰeh₂-*. This only shares the first consonant in common with  **bʰeydʰ*. (The vowel "e" included in the citation forms of most Proto-Indo-European roots is typically not a distinctive part of the root, but can be replaced according to the system of "ablaut" or "vowel gradation"). And it has nothing in common with the root **dʰeh₁*.

The path from *fātum* to *fairy* is somewhat complicated; I go over the hypothesized intermediate steps in my answer here: [Etymology of “fairy”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/391779/77227)